# How to address a specific JSON object

Tags: node.js, rest, api

I make a call to a REST-API and get a list of persons in JSON format. How do I just refer to one specific Object e.g. "Adam"?

I make the call via Node.js and would like to pass the Javascript object to another function.

I use:

```
request('rest-api-URL', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(response.body);    // Prints the JSON object
    var object = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(Object.keys(name)[0]);
  }
```

Maybe my problem is that I can not express my question clearly (and do not find any information)

This is the JSON:

```
"persons": [
        {
            "name": "Adam",
            "age": "20",
        },
               {
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": "21",
        },        {
            "name": "Christy",
            "age": "22",
        }    
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood yuor question correctly, you want to select an object baseed on the name property.

Given the `persons` array you can filter an object by name like:

```
function select(objects, name) {
  return objects.filter(obj => obj.name === name)[0];
}

const adamObject = select(persons, 'Adam');
```

Alternatively you can use Lodash's filter https://lodash.com/docs/#filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript filter() function:

```
array.filter(entry => entry.name == 'Adam')[0]
```

filter() function will return an array of matching objects, hence the [0] at the end since it will return an array with one object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a find

```
var person = array.find(data => data.name === 'Adam');
```